# Cassandra get more than 10k rows

Tags: django, cassandra, cql

I am getting stuck with Cassandra `all()` query.

I am using the Django platform.  My query is to get all rows from Cassandra table.  But, CQL has some limit to 10k rows at a time.

Before, I have less than 10k rows in Cassandra table.  But, now the count has increased up-to 12k.

How do I get the `all()` query to return all 12k rows?

Comment: Remember that running an unbound query in Cassandra is an anti-pattern.  You should design your table so that you don't need to query all of the rows at once.  As you continue to add rows, that query will eventually stop working and time out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CQL have a *default* limitation to 10k rows. That means there's an *implicit* limit to 10k when you perform any `SELECT`. If you want you can override that by specifying a new `LIMIT` value, eg:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 500000;
```

Comment: can we get it by django models query??

Comment: .all().limit(500000) ?